# Remove an outer multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have an array like this ( it has an array inside an array. Each parent array have more that just one child array )

```
 $value4old = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 112
                    [id_tindak_lanjut] => 30.3
                    [nilai_tindak_lanjut] => 0
                    [memo_tindak_lanjut] => 
                    [tindak_lanjut_no] => 1
                    [tgl_tindak_lanjut] => 2018-01-30
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 111
                    [id_tindak_lanjut] => 30
                    [nilai_tindak_lanjut] => 0
                    [memo_tindak_lanjut] => 
                    [tindak_lanjut_no] => 2
                    [tgl_tindak_lanjut] => 2018-01-07
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 110
                    [id_tindak_lanjut] => 20.3
                    [nilai_tindak_lanjut] => 0
                    [memo_tindak_lanjut] => 
                    [tindak_lanjut_no] => 2
                    [tgl_tindak_lanjut] => 2017-10-24
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 108
                    [id_tindak_lanjut] => 10.2
                    [nilai_tindak_lanjut] => 0
                    [memo_tindak_lanjut] => 
                    [tindak_lanjut_no] => 1
                    [tgl_tindak_lanjut] => 2018-01-19
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 109
                    [id_tindak_lanjut] => 30.3
                    [nilai_tindak_lanjut] => 0
                    [memo_tindak_lanjut] => Tes
                    [tindak_lanjut_no] => 2
                    [tgl_tindak_lanjut] => 2018-01-22
                )

        )

)
```

I tried to remove my parent array ( that one array before the child array ), and leave the child array, so it makes the child array turn into parents array.

what i expect is just like below:

```
Array
    (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 112
                        [id_tindak_lanjut] => 30.3
                        [nilai_tindak_lanjut] => 0
                        [memo_tindak_lanjut] => 
                        [tindak_lanjut_no] => 1
                        [tgl_tindak_lanjut] => 2018-01-30
                    )
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 111
                        [id_tindak_lanjut] => 30
                        [nilai_tindak_lanjut] => 0
                        [memo_tindak_lanjut] => 
                        [tindak_lanjut_no] => 2
                        [tgl_tindak_lanjut] => 2018-01-07
                    )
                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 110
                        [id_tindak_lanjut] => 20.3
                        [nilai_tindak_lanjut] => 0
                        [memo_tindak_lanjut] => 
                        [tindak_lanjut_no] => 2
                        [tgl_tindak_lanjut] => 2017-10-24
                    )
                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 108
                        [id_tindak_lanjut] => 10.2
                        [nilai_tindak_lanjut] => 0
                        [memo_tindak_lanjut] => 
                        [tindak_lanjut_no] => 1
                        [tgl_tindak_lanjut] => 2018-01-19
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 109
                        [id_tindak_lanjut] => 30.3
                        [nilai_tindak_lanjut] => 0
                        [memo_tindak_lanjut] => Tes
                        [tindak_lanjut_no] => 2
                        [tgl_tindak_lanjut] => 2018-01-22
                    )

    )
```

I tried this code

```
$in = count($value4old)-1; 
$val = array(); 
for ($i=0;$i<=$in;$i++) {   
$val = array_merge($value4old[$i]); 
};
print_r($val); 
echo "</pre>";
```

but i got like below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 108
            [id_tindak_lanjut] => 10.2
            [nilai_tindak_lanjut] => 0
            [memo_tindak_lanjut] => 
            [tindak_lanjut_no] => 1
            [tgl_tindak_lanjut] => 2018-01-19
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 109
            [id_tindak_lanjut] => 30.3
            [nilai_tindak_lanjut] => 0
            [memo_tindak_lanjut] => Tes
            [tindak_lanjut_no] => 2
            [tgl_tindak_lanjut] => 2018-01-22
        )

)
```

What could go wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to do this and your code should work as well, but you made a small error in your `array_merge`:

You wrote:

```
$val = array_merge($value4old[$i]);
```

What you need is

```
$val = array_merge($val, $value4old[$i]);
```

Basically you are just doing an assignment every time instead of a merge and you end up with the last value.

Answer (score 2):

```
$new = [];
foreach ($value4old as $array) {
    foreach($array as $inner) {
        $new[] = $inner;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove the outer array (when it has only one value) I always use `current()`.

```
$array = [
    '0' => ['key' => 'value'];
];

$array = current($array);
```

Will result in:

```
array(1) {
    'key' => 'value'
}
```

For an array with multiple keys that needs to be flattened, I suggest just using a `foreach` loop.

```
$newArray = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $newArray[$key] = current($value);
}
```

Comment: array with key "3" have more than one value... it has two value

Comment: @Gagantous I guess I've overlooked that.